# Does rooting (but no custom roms) trigger knox's void warranty

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-knox

Does it make Knox's "void warranty" = 0x1

Answer (score 2):

There are two events that will trigger the Knox flag to change from 0x0 to 0x1.

1. Unsigned recovery (recovery.img) is flashed
2. Unsigned kernel (boot.img) is flashed

It's not the actual custom rom that trips Knox when you get to flashing. It's the step before that, getting a custom recovery loaded in order to flash the rom itself.

This is also why the de-la-vega root method works, because it flashes a prerooted stock system image to your device without touching the two partitions that DO trip Knox of modified.

Answer (score 0):

Lucky boy! When I did the root procedure on my Galaxy S4, I did not figure out that I was going to lost my warranty increasing the Knox counter... Infact almost any root procedure will do this.
But, as I told you before, you are lucky because there is some new root-procedure that will not increase the Knox counter. You can read further on this: http://www.theandroidsoul.com/universal-root-de-la-vega-script/

Hope I've helped you!

Luca

Comment: Have you actually tried this?

Comment: The linls are dead on that site and in the comments people were having a lot of trouble

Comment: I did not tried it by myself cause I already did the "classic" root procedure with the Chainfire CF-AutoRoot. I'm sorry but I can't help you more :(